# Как создать boot раздел в Gparted в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, диск

Как создать boot раздел в Gparted в Ubuntu?

При создании раздела, какой тип нужно выбирать?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

В качестве файловой системы вибирайте ext3 (некоторые выбирают ext2, но это сильно на любителя). Размер лучше взять под 500Мб. Можно конечно и 200 взять, но если захочется экспериментов, несколько ядер, то может быть мало (у меня сейчас 600М). Также нужно выбрать "управление метками" в меню и выставить там флажок "boot".

Если же у вас gpt и хочется с uefi грузится, тогда нужен esp (efi special partition) и тип этого раздела (для загрузки) должен быть fat32. (да, для /boot можно сделать отдельный, а можно совместно с esp использовать)